# Android/Eclipse: Error in importing a project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was trying to import an android project on Eclipse, but I had this problem at the "Problems" tabs:

Project 'Chat' is missing required library: 'D:\Android Projects\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\platforms\android-18\android.jar'

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

I'm running Eclipse on Windows 7 with the following versions of things installed

Eclipse Luna - 4.4.2

Android Development Tools - Version: 23.0.6.1720515

Android SDK - 23.0.5

Any suggestions ??

Comment: did you using library ?

Answer (score 0):

Open Android SDK Manager in Eclipse and install SDK Platform 18 (Android 4.3.1 API 18):

[image]